# Read from Google spreadsheet and get html formatting

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am learning Python Google Spreadsheet API. Looking at the Google quickstart guide here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python I am able to get the code working

The issue I am running into is it is printing the content from the spreadsheet normally to my command prompt. I tested against a spreadsheet that has different formatting, such as bullets, numbered list, bold, underline, etc and it just basically prints out what it can.

Is it possible to read from the sheet and get a html version of the content? So for like bold it should be

```
<b>the word</b>
```

I am also trying to gather the info in HTML of what is bullets, numbered lists, tabs, etc.

I plan to basically read a spreadsheet and then display the exact info on a HTML page, but the formatting would all be lost.

Comment: Very generalized - you can use functions like .isBold() or .isItallic() to find out what the text is, then create some sort of statement that returns the proper formatting if true.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#isBold()

Comment: That would only work if the entire cell it is copying is bold. Else I would have to do some large amount of parsing each cell and dissecting it to figure out which word is bold. Also, it wouldn't help for things like bullets either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

To get the information about the text format of a cell, use the `spreadsheets.get` API [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get).
It is in the response's [CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#CellData) (at `sheets.data.rowData.values`), in both the `userEnteredFormat` and `effectiveFormat` fields.

However, the structure of `CellData` and consequently, `CellFormat` is an object:

```
{
  "numberFormat": {
    object (NumberFormat)
  },
  "backgroundColor": {
    object (Color)
  },
  "backgroundColorStyle": {
    object (ColorStyle)
  },
  "borders": {
    object (Borders)
  },
  "padding": {
    object (Padding)
  },
  "horizontalAlignment": enum (HorizontalAlign),
  "verticalAlignment": enum (VerticalAlign),
  "wrapStrategy": enum (WrapStrategy),
  "textDirection": enum (TextDirection),
  "textFormat": {
    object (TextFormat)
  },
  "hyperlinkDisplayType": enum (HyperlinkDisplayType),
  "textRotation": {
    object (TextRotation)
  }
}
```

So you need to manually build your HTML from code.

Comment: So if would need to run spreadsheets.get in a loop for my range? And then for each request on a cell it will return the above object which I can parse and build my HTML code? Also would this give me the correct response if the cell contained a paragraph with multiple words being bold and it also included a bullet list?

Comment: You can enter the range as a parameter to a single request and get multiple ````CellData```` objects. Also, if there are multiple formats in each cell, there are also multiple ````TextFormatRun```` objects as well.

The caveat is bullet lists are not captured yet in the API.

Comment: Ah. I am honestly more worried about the bullets than the bold. I did convert the response from the example in the OP into bytes and I should be able to mix both of these into getting it to work how I want. Thanks!

Comment: Much appreciated!